# How to refer to a class list item?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I'm a beginner at Python and I don't know what to set **command** to so I can open one of the links in the **class list** (Sorry if I am calling it the wrong thing. Please include what to call it in your answer.) For example, if I wanted to open Slopes link, what would I type in the **command** for **button_slope**?

```
import webbrowser
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

style = ttk.Style()
style.configure("TButton",
                font="Serif 15",
                padding=10)

class GameLibrary:
    def __init__(self, game, link):
        self.game = game
        self.link = link

games = [
    GameLibrary("Slope", "https://www.y8.com/games/slope"),
    GameLibrary("Punch Boxing Championship", "https://www.y8.com/games/punch_boxing_championship"),
]

main_frame = Frame(root)
main_frame.pack()
main_frame.grid(row=0, columnspan=4)

button_slope = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Slope', command='what do i type here').grid(row=1, column=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please don't tag your question with Python 2 *and* Python 3, as I highly doubt you're using both at the same time.

Answer (score 3):

`command` should be set to a callback function that executes when the button is pressed. For instance.

```
def callback():
    print "click!"

button_slope = ttk.Button(main_frame, text='Slope', command=callback)
button_slope.grid(row=1, column=0)
```

Will print `click!` when you click the button. You would want to take whatever action is appropriate for your program.